# JUNG specifying left and right children in a tree

Tags: java, graph, tree, jung

I am currently making a binary tree visualization application with JUNG using `DelegateTree`. However, I fail to find a way to explicitly state whether a node should be a left or a right child.

Initially I thought that I only need to use `addChild(edge, parent, child)` and just keep adding nodes in the same order. Later tho, I realized that this method does not always work. At first the produced tree seems correct but once it gets past height 3, it starts messing up and switching nodes and eventually whole subtrees in no particular fashion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you give some coding that you have done yet, so that people can help you better?

Answer (score 0):

DelegateTree does not itself guarantee any particular ordering for the iteration over neighbors (children).  If its input graph guarantees this ordering (see [JUNG: placing tree nodes in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215718/jung-placing-tree-nodes-in-order)) then you should be OK.

You also can use OrderedKAryTree for this: http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/OrderedKAryTree.html

Since you know that you have a binary tree in particular, you can also create a more efficient implementation of your own that assumes that all nodes have <= 2 children.

Comment: I tried OrderedKAryTree but tree.addEdge((String)label,(String)parent,(String)child) gives an exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'index' must be in [0, [order-1]]

I tried different sizes when setting the order and still get the same results.